# Как сделать, чтобы товары сохранялись в корзине?

Tags: php

Сейчас при добавлении нового товара в корзину, старый товар пропадает. Как сделать, чтобы товары сохранялись в корзине

```
cart.php

<?php
class CartItem{
    public $id;
    public $price = 0;
    public $count = 1;
    public $total_price = 0;

    public function __construct($id=NULL, $price=0, $count=1){
        if(isset($id)){
            $this->id = $id;
            $this->price = $price;
            $this->count = !$count?1:$count;
            $this->totalPrice();
        }
    }

    function totalPrice(){
        $this->total_price = $this->price * $this->count;
        return $this->total_price;
    }
}

class Cart{
    protected $items = array();

    function add(CartItem $cartItem){
        if(isset($this->items[$cartItem->id])){
            $cartItem->count += $this->items[$cartItem->id]->count;
        }
        $this->edit($cartItem);
    }

    function edit(CartItem $cartItem) {
        $cartItem->totalPrice();
        $this->items[$cartItem->id] = $cartItem;
    }

    function delete($id){
        unset($this->item[$id]);
    }

    function emptyCart(){
        $this->items=array();
    }

    function count(){
        $count = 0;
        foreach($this->get() as $cartItem) $count += $cartItem->count;
        return $count;
    }

    function total(){
        $total = 0;
        foreach($this->get() as $cartItem) $total += $cartItem->total_price;
        return $total;
    }

    function get($id=null){
        if(isset($id)) return $this->items[$id];
        else return $this->items;
    }
}
```

```
index.php


<?php
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "config.php";
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/classes/cart.php";
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products';
$stmt = $link->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'product_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "product_price", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

$cart =& $_SESSION["cart"];

if(!is_object($cart)) $cart = new Cart;
$cart = new Cart;
if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
    $cart->add(new CartItem($id, $price));
}
var_dump($cart);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Shop</title>
</head>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID товара</th><th>Цена</th><th>Кол-во</th><th>Сумма</th>
        <?php foreach($cart->get() as $product){?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $product->id;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->price;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->count;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->total_price?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php };?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Всего товаров:</td>
        <td><?php echo $cart->count();?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">На сумму:</td>
        <td><?php echo $cart->total();?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<body>
    <div class="cart">

    </div>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>Uniqlo</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="first-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Catalog</a>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="sub-menu-index">
                            <h3>Mac</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">Macbook</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">Imac</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">Macpro</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">Macmini</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="sub-menu-index">
                            <h3>Iphone</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">Iphone13</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">Iphone12</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">IphoneSE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="sub-menu-index">
                            <h3>Ipad</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">IpadPro
                        </a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">IpadAir</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">IpadMini</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="sub-menu-index">
                            <h3>AirPods</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">AirPods Max</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">AirPods Pro</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">AirPods 3</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="#">AirPods 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="second-menu">
            <li class="search-button"><img src="img/search.svg"  width="20px" alt="search">
            </li>
            <form class="search-window" action="" merhod="GET">
                <input type="text"></form>
            <li><img src="img/heart.svg"  width="20px" alt="wishlist"></li>
            <li><img src="img/cart2.svg" height="23px" alt="cart"></li>
        </ul>
        
    </header>
    <!-- Слайдер -->
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Первый слайд">
            <div class="slideText">Заголовок слайда 1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Второй слайд">
            <div class="slideText">Заголовок слайда 2</div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Третий слайд">
            <div class="slideText">Заголовок слайда 3</div>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="minusSlide()">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlide()">&#10095;</a>
        <div class="slider-dots">
            <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
            <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
            <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Конец слайдера -->

    <!-- Раздел Sale -->
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="product-list-title">Sale</h3>
        <div class="product-list">
            <?php
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM products';
            $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            
            foreach($result as $item){            
            ?>
            <div class="product">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $item['image'];?>" alt="img">
                    <div class="overlay">
                    <form id="form" name="form" method="POST"  action=""><br>
                        <label><br>
                        <input type="hidden"  name="product_price" value="<?php echo $item['price']; ?>"  /><br>
                        <input type="hidden"  name="product_id" value="<?php echo $item['id']; ?> "/><br>
                        <input type="submit"  name="Submit" value="В корзину" /><br>
                        </label><br>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $item['title'];?></a></h4>
                <span class="price"><?php echo $item['price'];?>$</span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-footer">
        <footer>
            <span>tel</span>
            <span>Privacy Policy | Your California Privacy Rights</span>
            <span>© UNIQLO CO. LTD. All rights reserved.</span>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$cart = new Cart;` вот проблемная строчка. Вы каждый раз инициализируете корзину, вместо того чтобы грузить её из сессии.

Comment: Без этой строчки у меня появляется ошибка, хотя присутствует проверка, создана ли корзина

Comment: Так исправляйте ошибку

Comment: Не получается исправить ошибку. Все равно выдает содержимое объекта и Fatal error: Uncaught Error: The script tried to call a method on an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Cart" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php on line 37

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664257/the-script-tried-to-execute-a-method-or-access-a-property-of-an-incomplete-objec